# Does the April 22, 2020 Executive Order suspending the entry of immigrants affect existing green card holders?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I am a Green Card holder since 07/28/2019 and I am outside USA now , will I get effected or ban from entry because of President recent executive order to ban the immigration for 60 days?

Comment: I don't know which reports you have read, but the BBC writes: **President Donald Trump has said he will halt *applications of foreign nationals seeking* permanent residence in the US because of the coronavirus crisis.** Until the the final text has been published (expected later today) nobody can say more than that. [Coronavirus: US green cards to be halted for 60 days, Trump says - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-52377122)

Comment: While I agree with @MarkJohnson that it's hard to say more without the final text, "I am a Green Card holder" says to me that you have already immigrated - a ban on immigration would be for people applying

Comment: Just to confirm, you have presumably been in the US since you received your green card, you are physically in possession of the green card, and you haven't breached any conditions of your permanent residence?

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain the way the US system works, it's not possible to get a green card without having been physically present in the US.  One either arrives in the US with an immigrant visa, in which case one becomes a permanent resident immediately on admission and subsequently gets the card, or one "adjusts status" while in the US.

Answer (score 5):

According to the text of [the proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspending-entry-immigrants-present-risk-u-s-labor-market-economic-recovery-following-covid-19-outbreak/) suspending entry, it does not apply to permanent residents (i.e. green card holders), so it should not affect your return to the US. See section 2(b)(1) of the proclamation:

> (b)  The suspension and limitation on entry pursuant to section 1 of
>   this proclamation shall not apply to:
>
> (i)     any lawful permanent resident of the United States;